# Code cleanup and optimization, where to start?

Tags: optimization, code-cleanup

I want to optimize my angularjs frontend application and cleanup the code to provide better code quality.

I thought about bringing in more abstraction, since I implemented a lot of similiar looking, but slightly different controllers.

My question(s) are the following:

- Are there common techniques to recognize bad code and optimize it?
- How can one determine if code is either good, bad or redundant?
- Where should one start, when trying to provide better code quality in
  an existing software project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your questions:

1. Yes there are: by looking at the code itself experienced programmers can tell if the code has certain characteristics or not. Some metrics exist that could indicate alarm signals in terms of quality like "many dots" in object-oriented languages (same in Javascript) which indicates close coupling. Here is a [comprehensive list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_metric).
2. By looking at it or as written before with static code analysis.
3. As others stated don't optimize or refactor just for the sake to have a good looking code base. When you need to touch existing code again to e.g. add a feature or fix a bug then start to look for code redundancies and many other signals that might indicate to refactor the code. Martin Fowler wrote an excellent [book](https://martinfowler.com/books/refactoring.html) about it with step-by-step examples which IMO is a must-read for every developer. Also a good starting point is Misko's [site](http://misko.hevery.com/code-reviewers-guide/). He talks about testability but "good" code is well testable.

What's really important before refactoring is to have a strong automated test base to rely on. If not add tests and go really slow to make sure you don't break existing functionality.

The topic is really huge and impossible to work through in a post here but I think it's one of the most important ones that makes an experienced programmer.

Answer (score 1):

If a code is good or bad is your own opinion.

To make the code look better and more efficient I would do something like this:

- Don't make the lines to long.
- Use variables that make sense.
- Use tabs and enter when it is too messy.

There are a whole lot more things to clean up your code, but these are just some examples.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, do you have personal techniques to keep things more abstract and reusable ?

Comment: I tend to make it as clean as possible such as using tabs and enters where needed. Most of the time you don't have to put much effort in the clean up.

Answer (score 1):

If the code works - don't touch it :)

Then when you work on bug fixes or new features\changes - see if you can also gradually improve pieces of code you are working with. The more you work with the code the better understanding of overall picture you should get and opportunities to improve and optimize should become more obvious. (you should also continue learning from other sources - books, internet, other codebases)

There is now magic "one size fits all" solution :) but yes, you can start with simple style changes as suggested in the other answer.

Answer (score 1):

The process you refer to is commonly known as [Refactoring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_refactoring). There are a number of standard techniques for improving code; Martin Fowler's book "Refactoring" has a list, with examples.

Many popular IDEs have refactoring tools built-in.

One of the processes in agile development is known as "red/green/refactor". Red means your code doesn't pass its unit tests; green means it passes (i.e. it does what it's supposed to do), and "refactor" means you make it elegant, maintainable and clean. Because you have a unit test, you know the refactoring doesn't break the code.

Where to start is a tough question - I typically recommend refactoring when you're fixing bugs. You may as well write a unit test to expose the bug, and tidy up the code while fixing the bug. Because that module has a bug, it's likely to be high-risk, so you should improve the code quality.